# Payment form that processes through paypal?

Tags: paypal

right now when someone clicks a Buy button on my website, it goes to the paypal login page. Below the login is the "Don't have an account?" tab that, when clicked, displays the full payment form and allows people without an account to manually fill it in and make their payment. I was wondering if there is a way for paypal Buy buttons to default to the manual form page, with the paypal user login as a secondary option instead. Or, even better, if there is a form that I can set up that someone could fill in with their payment information and then, when submitted, it would process through paypal (a link for users to login for easy access payment could be included on the side). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

With a basic buy now button you can't control it.  If you switch to the Express Checkout API you can force the Guest Checkout option by including the following parameters:

SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing

Unfortunately, PayPal is in the process of migrating all merchant accounts into a new set of Express Checkout flow pages that eliminates this option.  It's very annoying, and I (as well as many others) are griping at them about it, but it's not looking like they're going to change it back.

What they prefer is that you sign up for Payments Advanced or Payments Pro if you're going to be processing credit cards directly.  You could also use the new REST API which allows you to process cards and doesn't require Advanced or Pro.